# How to bind a new list of values to UL when Onchange event of Select option is fired using knockout.js?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, single-page-application

In my spa, after page loaded event ul showing some list of values from database successfully.
Below is the code

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true" data-bind="foreach: Cs">
    <li data-theme="c">
        <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide" data-bind="attr: { title: CID }">
            <span data-bind="text: FName + ' ' + LName +')'"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

function SSSmodel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Cs = $.parseJSON(localStorage["CsTab"]);
    self.SearchCs = function () {
        alert("Onchange event is fired");
    }
 };
```

While firing Onchange event in select then it calling 'SearchCs' in above function and showing alert also successfully .But i don't know how to bind new list of values to ul in that function?? below is select option code.It doesn't show any error.

```
<select id="ddlClassify" name="" data-theme="c" data-bind="event: {change: SearchCs}, options: ClassifiyData, optionsValue: 'ClassifyID', optionsText: function (i) { return i.Classify + ':' + i.Position }, optionsCaption: 'All'">
```

After page loaded event, binding some datas to UL and it showing that data in webpage successfully. But I don't know How to bind a new list of values to UL when Onchange event of Select option is fired?

Please guide me friends.

Comment: can't you just make the Contacts array an observable and then update it?

Comment: Hi maruizio, I tried that also.but its not working.. self.Contacts = ko.observableArray();self.Contacts = $.parseJSON(localStorage["ContactsTable"]);

Comment: can you please post a jsfiddle example with test data?

Comment: no yuo have to assign it like a function 'self.Contacts($.parseJSON(localStorage["ContactsTable"]));'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as like given below:

```
self.Contacts = ko.observable($.parseJSON(localStorage["ContactsTable"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make the Contacts array an observable and then update it like this:

```
self.Contacts($.parseJSON(localStorage["ContactsTable"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, made Jquery Ajax call , then only it will retrieve data are bind to UL.

```
  function SSSmodel() {
var self = this;
self.Cs = ko.observable($.parseJSON(localStorage["CsTab"]));

self.SearchCs = function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:12345/api/Ct',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: { ID: id },
        context: this,
        success: function (result) {
            debugger;
            self.Cs(result);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });

}   };
```